# Java semaphore increment count with specified threads

Tags: java, multithreading, count, semaphore

Does anybody know why after compiling this code, (i think) one thread still waiting for something?
I want to increment a count with the threads with id 10,11 and 12 one after one, until 50.
In the end, it works, but the red button (terminate) is still red, which means that the program it's still running, and probably waiting for something.

I think that when the count is 50, the return should work and exit from method. Maybe it does, but is not sufficient.

Here's the code:

```
public class App12 {

    Semaphore sem1 = new Semaphore(1);
    Semaphore sem2 = new Semaphore(0);
    Semaphore sem3 = new Semaphore(0);

    int count = 0;

    public void inc() throws InterruptedException {

        while (true) {
            if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == 10) {
                sem1.acquire();
                if (count != 50) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " has incremented " + count);

                    sem2.release();
                } else
                    return;
            }

            if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == 11) {
                sem2.acquire();
                if (count != 50) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " has incremented " + count);

                    sem3.release();
                } else
                    return;

            }

            if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == 12) {
                sem3.acquire();
                if (count != 50) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " has incremented " + count);

                    sem1.release();
                } else
                    return;

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        App12 ap = new App12();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Thread th1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        ap.inc();
                        // dec3();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            th1.start();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what is the use of the parameter passed into the constructor?

Comment: Here i'm using the default constructor, i could change the method to static and just call the method.

Comment: But i don't have nothing to pass here from constructor.

Comment: "In the end, it works" - how do you come to that conclusion? - In your "else" paths, you do not release the semaphores. So even if for example thread with id 10 reaches count = 50, it won't allow the others to return from acquire. - I hope, this is not production code, by the way ...

Comment: Because one thread increment the count at 50, and it stops, but the program is still running. You can try it for yourself.

Comment: It's my code, i did it in C (but with a file), and translated in java. Thread 11 increment the counter at 50, and then, sem3 is release, then comes the thread 12 but the count is 50, so it's acquired (at 0) and the next thread (10) is not released, instead it goes in else statement and return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you never release the locks on the threads, and they end up waiting forever.

From your logic, Thread A release B releases C.

However, once you hit 50, Thread A returns. Never releasing Thread B and C.

So what you need is an exit condition releasing all other waiting threads.

For example (in your while loop):

```
if(count == 50) {
                sem2.release();
                sem3.release();
                sem1.release();
            }
```

The issue is that once 11 or 12 increment they immidiatelly enter the loop again, at which point they lock on the semathor waiting to be released. If your count however was 50, the thread releasing it will return without ever entering your if condition.

Alternatively, you should be able to add a release on the else clause, so all threads get released.

Hope that helps,

Artur

EDIT: Here is your full code with the fix implemented:

```
public class App12 {

    Semaphore sem1 = new Semaphore(1);
    Semaphore sem2 = new Semaphore(0);
    Semaphore sem3 = new Semaphore(0);

    int count = 0;

    public void inc() throws InterruptedException {

        while (true) {

            if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == 10) {
                sem1.acquire();
                if (count != 50) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " has incremented " + count);
                    sem2.release();
                } else {
                    sem2.release();
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == 11) {
                sem2.acquire();
                if (count != 50) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " has incremented " + count);
                    sem3.release();
                } else {
                    sem3.release();
                    return;
                }

            }

            if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == 12) {
                sem3.acquire();
                if (count != 50) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " has incremented " + count);
                    sem1.release();
                } else {
                    sem1.release();
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        App12 ap = new App12();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Thread th1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        ap.inc();
                        // dec3();
                        System.out.println("Exist ");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            th1.start();
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I am releasing the semathors once the count is 50, so that the other threads can exit.

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much : )

Answer (score 0):

Release locks to finish threads.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class App12 {

Semaphore sem1 = new Semaphore(1);
Semaphore sem2 = new Semaphore(0);
Semaphore sem3 = new Semaphore(0);


int count = 0;

public void inc() throws InterruptedException {

    while (true) {

        if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == 10) {
            sem1.acquire();
            if (count != 50) {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " has incremented " + count);

            } else {
                sem2.release();
                return;
            }
            sem2.release();

        }

        if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == 11) {
            sem2.acquire();
            if (count != 50) {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " has incremented " + count);

            } else {
                sem3.release();
                return;
            }
            sem3.release();
        }

        if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == 12) {
            sem3.acquire();
            if (count != 50) {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " has incremented " + count);

            } else {
                sem1.release();
                return;
            }
            sem1.release();

        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    App12 ap = new App12();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Thread th= new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ap.inc();
                    // dec3();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        th.start();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's just for me, i want to control the threads, that's why i use 3 semaphores. But thanks.

Comment: Tis does not work. It changes the logic that he is trying to achieve. If you take a look at the code, what he is trying to achieve is to synchronise the threads so that each of them increments the counter IN TURN. With your solution there is no order on which thread is doing the next increment, while with his logic it goes 10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 12 ...